# Separate Response for the two recipients phpmailer function

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I want to send separate response for two different recipients in phpmailer function

```
if($mail->addAddress($email, $name)){
    $mail->Body = "Thanks for your response. our representative contact you soon....";
}

if($mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'xxxx')){
    $mail->Body = $message;
}
```

Comment: Create a new mailer instance?

Comment: how to create ?

Comment: The same way you created the first one.

Comment: Don't need to create a new instance, just send one, change the bits that need changing, send the second one. Look at the clear* functions in the PHPMailer docs.

Comment: Synchro Kindly give example for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link may be help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34428438/php-mailer-user-email-getting-sent-to-admin)

you to create the separate instance for admin and client it will be easy like Jon Striling said

Comment: Thanks Kousik daniel this is help for me